# singluar values unchanged when multiplied with an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

revisiting

[singular values of "rotated" matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083309/singular-values-of-rotated-matrix)

Maybe I've since forgotten - or maybe I never bothered to ask myself - but

> Since $A^T$ has the same singular values as $A$ and $K$ is orthogonal, conclude that [        $A^\top K$        ] indeed has the same singular values.

Why does this hold?

Why can we say that multiplying by an orthogonal matrix retains the singular values?

Comment: The (nonzero) singular values of $A$ are related to the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ which are in turn related to the eigenvalues of $AA^T$. Now for $B=A^TK$ you have $BB^T=A^TA$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We calculate the singular values of $A$ by decomposing it into $A=USV^T$ with diagonal $S$ and orthogonal $U$ and $V$. If we have another orthogonal $K$, we have $AK= USV^TK = U  S (V^TK)$ which is the SVD of $AK$.

Comment: I see, and $V^\top K $ is orthogonal because $V^\top K (V^\top K)^\top = V^\top K K^\top V = I $. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = UDV^T$ be the singular value decomposition.

If you premultiply it with $K$, $KA=(KU)DV^T$

$KU$ is an orthogonal matrix as well. In fact $(KU)DV^T$ is a singular value decomposition for $KA$. The $D$ matrix is not changed.

Similar reasoning for post-multiplication.