# "rotating" a matrix instead of transposing it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a silly question asked just out of curiosity. The question has nothing to do with rotation matrices as far as I know, but I didn't know how else to refer to the following operation.

In linear algebra, suppose I have an $m\times n$ matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then suppose I "rotate" the elements of this matrix by 90 degrees to get an $n\times m$ matrix

$$
A^\circlearrowright = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{11} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{mn} & \dots & a_{1n}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This is similar to the transpose, in that the transpose $A^T$ reflects the matrix $A$ along its diagonal, while $A^\circlearrowright$ rotates it by 90 degrees instead.

The question is just whether this "rotation" operation has any sensible meaning when $A$ is interpreted as a linear transformation. I am guessing the answer is no, but it seemed worth asking anyway, just in case it's something that's been considered for some reason.

A related operation is what we could call the "anti-transpose", which reflects the matrix along the 'other' diagonal and also results in an $n\times m$ matrix:

$$
A^\bot \begin{pmatrix}
a_{mn} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

An application of this anti-transpose operation is mentioned in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195031/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-off-diagonal-transpose/195044#195044) on mathoverflow. (Thanks to Torsten Schoeneberg for pointing that out.)

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/195031/27465

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thank you for that - I will update this question to link to that answer instead of asking about the anti-transpose

Comment: (1)If you treat it as a 2d image, you are performing a rotation, which is a linear transformation of the _coordinates_.(2) if you treat $A$ as an $m\times n$ _vector_, then you can find a $(m\cdot n)\times (m\cdot n)$ matrix that does this.

Comment: It might help to note that we have
$$
A^\circlearrowright = A^TJ,
$$
where $J$ is the $m \times m$ matrix such that
$$
J_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & i + j = m+1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: As is noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083309/81360), the singular values of $A^\circlearrowright$ are equal to the singular values of $A$. In particular, we have
$$
A^\circlearrowright [A^\circlearrowright]^T = A^TA.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks, that's helpful. So for a column vector $x$ with $m$ entries the operation $A^\circlearrowright x$ basically means "first turn $x$ upside-down (reversing the order of its elements) and then do the linear transformation $A^T$." That's simpler than I expected. I'd accept it if posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotated matrix can be expressed as
$$
A^\circlearrowright = A^TJ,
$$
where $J$ is the $m \times m$ matrix with entries
$$
J_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & i + j = m+1,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
We can see that $A^\circlearrowright$ has the same singular values as $A$ by noting that
$$
A^\circlearrowright [A^\circlearrowright]^T = A^TA.
$$
Interestingly, we also have the relation
$$
[A^\circlearrowright]^TA^\circlearrowright = [AA^T]^\perp.
$$